# Are IE7/IE8 browser/document modes in IE9 equivalent to the real browsers?

Tags: testing, internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

Our QA team needs to test our website in IE9, IE8, and IE7.

Rather than have separate machines for each IE version, could testers simply run IE9 in IE8 or IE7 mode?

For example, could a QA tester simply set the following and have and identical "IE8" experience:

- Browser Mode: IE8
- Document Mode: IE8 Standards

Has Microsoft made any specific recommendations on this?

(Our fallback option is to run VPC compatibility images, but that requires more effort to set up on testers' machines.)

Comment: Another option is http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage rather than separate machines/images.

Comment: I'd suggest reconsidering the VPC setup if you don't mind the large download size and you have the hardware to run multiple VPCs in the same machine. IMO, setting up VPC is the solution with the least hassles.

Comment: I am definitely comfortable with doing VPC. However, if I can find official MS source saying that using IE document modes are equivalent, that is much easier. (at my org, getting virtual PC installed on contractor's machines is a huge hassle)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the specific differences are, but on my last project I found that there were differences in the way IE9 rendered "past versions" and the way the virtual PC version behaved.  From here on out for sites where compatability is critical I will only be trusting "full installs" of the other browsers whether on a separate PC or a vitual machine.

Comment: any specific example of a difference between the emulated and real versions?

Answer (score 1):

In testing, you can never guarantee that software works unless proven to do so within the environment(s) it will be used in.

While IE9 will emulate rendering of IE8 and IE7, it does so using a different system than the actual IE8 and IE7. Even if the code used to access the emulation is the same as the actual, it is being accessed inside a different system (container).

That being said, I have found differences in seemingly identical browsers across platforms. In short, do not leave anything to chance. Test it on the actual platform (with VM).

I suggest testing all three browser versions on all supported platforms. If this is an important web application then consider using a testing tool like Selenium: http://seleniumhq.org

Answer (score 1):

We have to cross-IE test our applications, because our corporate clients use IE6, 7, and 8.  While there are emulators like [IECollection](http://finalbuilds.com/iecollection.htm), we have found that they get only 95% of the way there, and the remaining 5% will bite you.

We have settled on the following, and its free: [Microsoft VirtualPC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/default.aspx) with [Internet Explorer Application Compatibility VPC Images](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=11575).  These VMs, provided free of charge by Microsoft, are full Windows builds with specific Windows and IE versions that enable real-world testing.  The VMs expire every 3 months, but the 4-times a year hassle has been worth it for us, because if we certify on one of the VMs, we know that it works, as opposed to one of the emulators.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. If you are using IE9, Select Tools->F12 Developer tools. In status bar area you will find all together new Menu, in which you will find Browser Mode and Document Mode. You can change to IE7 or IE8 from there. Please refer the following image.
[image]